# If No Picture match then show msg box

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have the code below that works perfectly thanks to your guy's help but I have a code Im not sure how to do. For 'got a match: get sample of pic from VAST folder - I would like to show a msg box if no match is found. Is that possible without switching up my code too much?

```
Private Sub RejectTitleNm_Change()

    Dim f As Range, v

    v = Me.RejectTitleNm.Value

    ' find the selected value in the source range from ColB(RejectTitle)
    Set f = Range("RejectTitle").Find(v, lookat:=xlWhole)

    Me.TextBox1.Text = ""

    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        ' got a match: get value from ColC(Issue) on same row
        Me.TextBox1.Text = f.EntireRow.Cells(, "C").Value
        ' got a match: get value from ColD(TA) on same row
        Me.TextBox2.Text = f.EntireRow.Cells(, "D").Value
        ' got a match: get value from ColE(VBA) on same row
        Me.TextBox3.Text = f.EntireRow.Cells(, "E").Value

        ' REJECT ID
        ' got a match: get value from ColA(RejectID) on same row
        Me.RejectID.Text = f.EntireRow.Cells(, "A").Value

        ' CHANNELS
        ' got a match: get value from ColF(Mail) on same row
        Me.MailChannel.Text = f.EntireRow.Cells(, "F").Value
        ' got a match: get value from ColG(Web) on same row
        Me.WebChannel.Text = f.EntireRow.Cells(, "G").Value
        ' got a match: get value from ColG(Phone) on same row
        Me.PhoneChannel.Text = f.EntireRow.Cells(, "H").Value


        ' got a match: get sample of pic from reject folder
        RejectSamples.Image2.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\RejectExamples\" & RejectTitleNm.Value & ".jpg")

        ' got a match: get sample of pic from VAST folder
        Vexamples.VASTEx.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\VASTScreens\" & RejectTitleNm.Value & ".jpg")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: horrible comments, should use only meaningful comments that would help the person that may have to maintain the code

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub RejectTitleNm_Change()

    Dim f As Range, v

    v = Me.RejectTitleNm.Value                                  ' search value

    Set f = Range("RejectTitle").Find(v, lookat:=xlWhole)       ' search RejectTitle (column B)

    Me.TextBox1.Text = ""

    If Not f Is Nothing Then                                    ' update userForm from data in same row 

        Me.TextBox1.Text = f.EntireRow.Cells(, "C").Value       ' Issue (column C in "found" row)
        Me.TextBox2.Text = f.EntireRow.Cells(, "D").Value       ' TA
        Me.TextBox3.Text = f.EntireRow.Cells(, "E").Value       ' VBA

        Me.RejectID.Text = f.EntireRow.Cells(, "A").Value       ' RejectID

        ' CHANNELS
        Me.MailChannel.Text = f.EntireRow.Cells(, "F").Value    ' Mail
        Me.WebChannel.Text = f.EntireRow.Cells(, "G").Value     ' Web
        Me.PhoneChannel.Text = f.EntireRow.Cells(, "H").Value   ' Phone


        ' get sample of pic from reject folder
        RejectSamples.Image2.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\RejectExamples\" & RejectTitleNm.Value & ".jpg")

        ' get sample of pic from VAST folder
        Vexamples.VASTEx.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\VASTScreens\" & RejectTitleNm.Value & ".jpg")

    Else

        MsgBox "please check your input", vbExclamation, "No match found"

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't work. When there is no match I get a debug error for

Comment: Vexamples.VASTEx.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\VASTScreens\" & RejectTitleNm

Comment: Correction:      Vexamples.VASTEx.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\VASTScreens\" & RejectTitleNm.Value & ".jpg")

Comment: why did you not mention that in your question? the code has not been altered, just added to. what is the error?

Comment: I didn't change anything. I put the code in just like you did above. The error message is "Vexamples.VASTEx.Picture = <Object variable or With block variable not set>"

Comment: put your old code back in (the code that you put into your question above) and try it. you will get the same error .... there is something in _Range("RejectTitle")_ that should not be there, or something is wrong in _VASTScreens_ directory

Comment: I have not changed anything. The only thing I've done is add the code you provided.

Comment: i repeat. **put in the code that you posted in your question and try it**

Comment: Ooh sorry! If you said, "please provide me your full code again" I would have got it  LOL

Comment: Is that what you're asking?

Comment: If not are you saying to remove the "msg" code and try again? If so, I did that, it work fine without the "msg" code, but it will error if I select a combobox dropdown that does not have a corresponding .jpg

Comment: you said _I didn't change anything. I put the code in just like you did above. 
 ..._ , so i used the same wording as you. ....  what i want you to do is: **run your old code** (the code you posted)

Comment: Ok, I have and it works as long as I have a corresponding .jpg in the VASTScreens folder, if not then it errors out

Comment: the problem is that the find command is finding something. ... put  these two lines after the `set f = ...` line ...  `f.Interior.Color = vbRed`  `Stop` and run the code. the program will run up to Stop.  now, look at your worksheet and see which cell has turned red

Comment: Ok, I see...so "RejectTitle" column is still being found. Which is my combobox. So, maybe a stop and start after combobox?

Comment: when the code is stopped at the Stop. move the mouse pointer over the **v** in 
 `tTitle").Find(v, lookat`  or in `v = Me.Reject`. a ToolTip should display, showing the value of **v**.  what is that value?

Comment: The value is the next column over from the combobox selection. So it would be the Value of Column C

Comment: can you move a little closer? cannot see your computer screen from here.

Comment: anyway, that is your problem. there should be no value in variable **v** when there is no match found

Comment: it is too much work trying to get information from you. i will not help you any more. maybe someone else will.

Comment: Ok, I need my variable v value has to have a value it populates all my other fields.  The VASTexample is optional, it may be there it may not but if not I need a msg box to populate. I still want all the other textboxes to populate data.